# Python Net-SNMP, Linux: gather usernames by IP

Tags: python, linux, net-snmp

I would like to define usernames (or uids) of users currently logged into the remote hosts with static IP addresses. Of course there's a lot of ways to work it out (for instance - using PKI and sshd), but i prefer SNMP service.

I have seen some examples of this problem, something like this ([from here](http://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Unified-Wired-Wireless-Access/How-to-get-username-by-IP-address-from-MIB-SNMP/td-p/72350), for ArubaOS):

```
snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c secure 10.1.30.9 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.3
```

I am trying to implement this approach on Python and getting an error:

```
In [33]: import netsnmp

In [34]: oid = netsnmp.Varbind("nUserName")

In [35]: result = netsnmp.snmpget(oid, Version = 2, DestHost="localhost", Community="public")
error: get: unknown object ID (nUserName)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Using RHEL 6.4, Python 2.6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SNMP variable is enterprise-specific (.1.3.6.1.**4**.1) and specifically for an Aruba SNMP agent (hence the OID **14823**).

To do this for your particular scenario you'd need your Linux SNMP agent to return the same type of data, and you should inspect the corresponding MIB.